# What is snapshot utility in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, snapshot

I have seen the option of snapshot option in the File menu of Xcode.

But I don't know what it means.

- Where can the snapshot option can be used?
- Why would this option be used?
- Advantages of using this option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Where a snapshot option can be used?**

- A snapshot can be used after any modifications to your code.

**Why this option is used?**

- This option is used when you are making modifications that you are unsure of and might not want.

**Advantages of using this option?**

- The advantage is that you can simply fall back onto a previous snapshot if the desired changes didn't work out as you wanted.

Comment: So are we breaking the 10000 barrier tonight John?

Comment: na 1 more vote and im capped for 5 hours ;(

Comment: Oops - That was my last vote too :)

Comment: Now in 5 hours I can come back and see all the wasted upvotes. It's quite depressing really.